# Mechanical rigging

Tags: rigging

I need to make an animation of this big Vacuum Cleaner...

[image]

The green cube has a bone that follows the cube if I move it. This motion in X must cause another bone to rotate in Y which would cause the vacuum tubes to rotate in Y.

The bone that follows the green cube works. How do I make the bone that controls the vacuum rotate?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a [Transformation Constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ru/dev/rigging/constraints/transform/transformation.html). Rather than a straight copy of a transform between objects, this allows varying transform properties to control other channels and also allow a scaling factor.

[image: transformation panel]

In this example, changes to the x location of `Driver` changes the y rotation of `Target`. When `Driver` moves 5 units on x, `Target` will rotate 360 degrees. As I am using the x axis to drive the targets y axis the mapping in the middle needs to be set to match. The extrapolation option causes the transform to continue past the entered values.

If the source max location is changed to 2.5 the target will rotate twice as much for the same movement.

[image: sample usage]

Comment: I had try all the answers and the 1 I like is this one thes to both of U :)

Answer (score 0):

There will be multiple ways to do this including scripting.
Here are two  ways to do this.

**Using Drivers**
This is a way to influence the values of one property using the values of another property.The driving property could be a bone in the same armature or any other object. 
In your case for example you can get the X value of one bone to drive the Y rotation of another.

A quick summary of adding drivers from the WIKI

> The common way to add a driver to a property is to RMB click a property, then add a driver via the context menu. Drivers can also be added by pressing Ctrl-D with the mouse over the property set. The selected properties will be used as a destination (output) for the driver.
>
> Once added you can access then from the graph editor.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/ru/dev/animation/drivers/introduction.html

**Using action constraint**

Similar to drivers but uses an objects entire action (That is all the fcurves) to drive the target property.
Here is a summary from the WIKI

> The Action constraint is powerful. It allows you control an Action
>   using the transformations of another object.
>
> The underlying idea of the Action constraint is very similar to the
>   one behind the Drivers, except that the former uses a whole action
>   (i.e. a bunch a F-Curves of the same type), while the latter controls
>   a single F-curve of their “owner”...

https://docs.blender.org/manual/ru/dev/rigging/constraints/relationship/action.html

Hope this helps

-Cheerios

Comment: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." -- StackExchange answering guide. 

As it stands, this is not a good answer. It doesn't actually explain anything, it just provides links. Please either expand your answer or just leave the links as comments.

Comment: Edited the post..
Hope it works better now.
Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Thks for a fast answer :) i will try this helps