# Object to move and change with bone

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I'm trying to make an object get bigger when I move a bone forward without using the timeline how can I do this? I want to use this to make a gun with a flash when I shoot but I can't figure out how to make the flash get bigger when I move the bone forward

Comment: When you are talking about the "bone" do you mean a locator with a parent constraint? Just trying to get a better picture, of what you are trying to accomplish. I do know that you can animate a light source, on the timeline. Still fairly new to blender. But, it could have the same principles as Maya.

Comment: What I need is to be able to move a bone in a direction the when I move it in pose mode and as I move it an item can change its size or a lamp could get brighter as I move the bone forward

Comment: You could use drivers or a [transformation constraint](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/77569/935).